# Assembly and logic analyzer - sequence of execution

Tags: assembly

I have a question about very low-level thing. We were analyzing how the microprocessor performs simple assembler programs, we were using logic analyzer, so I have .law file. This is the code we used (in comments I placed opcodes):

```
mov ax, 1000
mov ds, ax
mov bx, 2000
mov ax, 0aa

mov cx, 100

petla
    push cx ;51
    mov [bx],al ;8807
    mov ax,[bx] ;8B07
    inc al;FEc0
    pop cx;59
loop ;here goes address
```

we wrote it in debug program, assembled and watched the output. Here is the image:

http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/241/mikro.png

now, here is the strange (at least for me) thing:

```
Data bus:51 - push cx
Data bus:8807 - mov [bx],al
Data bus:0001 - writing to 1EF6A
Data bus:8B07 - mov ax,[bx]
Data bus AA, address bus:12000 - that is writing al to [bx] (ds - 1000, bx - 2000)
```

All of a sudden he writes to some place in memory the value that is in the CX register (I suspect that 1EF6A is the physical address of the SS:SP). Is it because of the

```
push CX?
```

If yes, why does he do it after the

```
mov [bx],al
```

and why the writing to [bx] occurred so late?

I was thinking that pushing value to stack should be done immediately after the push instruction.

Comment: Artifact of out-of-order execution, probably.  I'd recommend getting your hands on a simpler CPU, like maybe an in-order ARM chip, and studying that first.

Comment: Well, that was only part of the micro-processors class, so I don't have any logic-analyzers at home. So you say that behaviour is not normal? Because I was thinking about consequences, if someone tried to read some part of memory with one instruction that is after mov [bx],al and he reads not updated value, because the writing occurs later in time.

Comment: No, that behavior is totally normal for a modern x86 chip.  It's just confusing if you're not expecting it, and has all kinds of hairy consequences -- you're thinking along the right lines when you wonder what happens if someone tries to read after the write.  (The CPU guarantees that an instruction in the _same thread_ will see memory as if the write happened, but another thread on another core may not -- read <http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt> for further enlightenment, but I warn you that it may make your head explode.)

Comment: Grr, buggy URL detection, I meant http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt . Anyway, what I was trying to get at with "get your hands on a simpler CPU" is, I think the x86 is much too complicated to be the _first_ CPU your class asks you to take a logic probe to.  Should start with something that runs in-order and has a write-through cache, ideally, and work your way up.  You may tell your instructor I said so. :)

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67 look at amber_samples and mips1_core_samples and some others (lsasim, meecoate).  I have a number of processor simulators and of those some (listed) produce .vcd waveform files you can view with gtkwave.  All of which are better than x86 for learning at this level if this is an educational thing.  I could probably make pcemu_samples output waveforms, but x86 is not a good processor for learning other than history.  Start elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Sorry, I don't yet have enough rep to comment, so I'm resorting to writing this an an answer.)

@Andna: this is an 8088, right?  That's why memory access in the analyzer trace is byte-at-a-time.  So what you're seeing is the result of the 8088's prefetch unit, which blindly reads instruction bytes from memory and holds them in a short (4-byte) prefetch queue in the hope that the execution unit will want to use them later.

Data operations that result from the instructions that the execution unit actually executes will appear on the bus some time later.  That's why the CX value written to memory doesn't show up immediately after the `push CX` instruction is read, and why the AL write doesn't appear on the bus until after the `MOV AX,[BX]` instruction has been read.  It's also why, at the end of the loop (which unfortunately is not shown in this trace snapshot), you'll see the prefetch unit reading instructions that come after the loop instruction.  However, the execution unit will not execute those instructions.

You're correct to worry about possible bad side effects of the prefetch unit's readahead, but the danger arises only when you're dealing with a memory location that is written after the prefetch unit has already collected the previous value from that location, and that can only happen when you're dealing with a memory location just above the current point of program execution.  If you're ever in that situation then you must do something to invalidate the content of the prefetch queue before you try to read that newly-written location.  Executing a `JMP` will do that.

@Zack: there's no out-of-order execution here, no multicore or multithreading, not even any cacheing.  Just a tiny amount of blind, speculative prefetch.  Yes, the prefetch does make following the trace very slightly trickier than, say, an 8085.

Comment: Gosh, I feel silly now.  I thought we were looking at something much newer!  (I still think a modern, but in-order, ARM core would be a better first CPU to analyze.  Or maybe a 6502.)